# Automatically wake from hibernation?

Tags: windows

I currently have my pc so that every day, it automatically hibernates at night at 11 pm.

Is it possible to make my pc automatically wake from hibernation at a certain time, preferably through task scheduler?

(Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

When Windows hibernates the system, the memory is written to the HDD, and the computer is physically shut down.  Windows is no longer running, and there is nothing you can do in Windows to wake it.

However, your computer's BIOS may have the option to automatically wake the computer at a certain time.  Generally, this may be listed as "Power On Timer" or some such language (each BIOS is different, so you'll have to figure out what your BIOS calls it).  Not all BIOSes have this feature.

---

If you are willing to put your computer to sleep instead of hibernate, Windows *can* wake the computer from sleep.  [This article from HowToGeek explains the process nicely](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/).  In summary:

1. Create a scheduled task.
2. Set it to the highest privileges.
3. Set a trigger for the wake time.
4. Under the "Conditions" tab, check the "Wake this computer" box.
5. Set the script action as something that doesn't do anything.  For example, `cmd.exe /c "exit"`.

Comment: If the BIOS supports ACPI properly and has wake timers then Task Scheduler can use those to wake the system up from hibernation too, although even with many laptops I've found that this only works as long as AC power is available.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for Windows 8, but in previous versions Control Panel > Windows Update had a setting to choose when to automatically install updates. The default value on my machine was Everyday at 3 AM, and when updates were available, that's exactly when my machine would wake from hibernation (yes, hibernation and not sleep or hybrid sleep) and install updates. There are no
settings in either my Windows Vista or BIOS regarding wake timers, but obviously Windows found them and used them. It's possible Windows Update created it's own scheduled task, but I surely didn't.

Comment: "There are no settings in either my Windows Vista or BIOS regarding wake timers" - Might not be exposed to end users in the BIOS (although that sounds unlikely if the feature is supported), but as for Vista, [are you sure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TjjPH.gif)?