How to suspend Windows PC for a specified period of time using Powershell?
Using Powershell or batch scripts, how to make a PC with Windows OS automatically suspend during the weekdays and automatically reactivate for every weekend?
I know that in Linux OS this can be achieved using inbuilt utilities like rtcwake, cron in shell scripts. I'm interested in doing something similar in Windows 10 or 11.

I am curious for a script. It could make the process automatic.
For instance when OpenSSH servers are installed on many PCs with Windows and then automatically login to many PCs with Windows through ssh and automatically run the scripts in cmd console that is available after ssh login. Or powershell when invoking powershell.exe in cmd console

This question appears to ask the same question you are asking, and it has answers. https://superuser.com/questions/898879/automatically-wake-from-hibernation

thanks for the information. I didn't find this question earlier, sorry. Maybe I will edit this question about script version for automatic sleep and automatic wake-up of PC with Windows
